# Rails Kaminari pagination and stored procedures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, kaminari

I have 2 stored procedures wich return data with limit and offset and count of all records.
How can I use Kaminari for pagination in this case ?

UPD
I have  problem with kaminari in edge version! I have abstract class MyRecord extended from ActiveRecord, other models extends this abstract class.

```
class Customer < MyRecord
has_one :active_order, :class_name => 'Order', 
:conditions => {
:status_type => [Order::STATUS_TYPES[:active],Order::STATUS_TYPES[:paused]]
}
```

.......

## controller

```
 @customers = Customer.search(params[:search]).includes(:active_order).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).page(params[:page]).per(25)
```

I get now wrong query  (abstract class table name instead of model table name)

```
  SELECT `my_records`.* FROM `my_records` WHERE 
        (`my_records`.customer_id IN (160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170) 
    AND (`my_records`.`status_type` IN (0, 2)))
```

Comment: Did you already looked the docs at github?

Comment: yeap I used is with ActiveRecord and also knw it can works with array , but in my case I don't have full array only a part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just added a new feature on Kaminari::PaginatableArray that would solve your problem.
 https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/pull/141

Can you bundle the edge version of Kaminari:

```
gem 'kaminari', :git => 'git://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari'
```

and pass `:total_count` option to `PaginatableArray#new` like this?

```
Kaminari::PaginatableArray.new(array, :total_count => 1326).page(5)
```

or

```
Kaminari::PaginatableArray.new(array, :total_count => 9999, :limit => 10, :offset => 30)
```

Comment: I have  problem with kaminari in edge version!

Comment: сhanged extension of AR to mixing and everything is ok , but it's buggy anyway =)